# Java: String index out of range: -4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

i got an error "String index out of range: -4" 
heres my code below

```
if (WHEREClause.substring((WHEREClause.length() - 4)) == "AND ") {
    WHEREClause = WHEREClause.substring(0, (WHEREClause.length() - 4)); }
```

the value of WHERECLAUSE IS => "arSLC_CODE=13 AND "

and if i display "WHEREClause.substring((WHEREClause.length() - 4))" from the code 
i get this => "AND "

so it looks like 
if("AND " ==  "AND ")
{
  ...i go inside here
}

but instead i got an error "String index out of range: -4" and can't get inside the if statement. please help still new to this

Comment: don't compare Strings using the == operator. Java isn't JavaScript

Comment: do you know how indices work in Java?

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`; use `.equals` method.

Comment: what do i use? do i use contains(char) ?

Comment: no, use equals. but it would seem that WhereClause.length() is 0. have you checked the value of WhereClause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing strings use the `.equals` instead of `==`. `==` is usually used only when comparing references or memory, while `.equals` is used when to see if they contain the same content

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Alex Tănăsescu is right, use `.equals` to compare `string` content.

Secondly, it looks like `WHEREClause` attribute may contain an empty string. Are you sure that the exception is throwing inside `if` block? I'm convinced that it appears earlier in this peace of code:

```
WHEREClause.substring((WHEREClause.length() - 4))
```

Just check if the `string` is empty.